# Read individual values separated by commas per line c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to read a text file and import each value separated by a comma on each line, on more than one line. I have already done it in VB.Net but I can not seem to figure how to do it in C#.

My text file looks like this:

12345678,you smell,1,0.50

73432433,listen,5,9

As you can see on each line, there is 4 values separated by a comma.
How can I set each individual value to an array in my program? And be able to import the next line.
I have tried this, to see if i can see each value.

```
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("stock.txt");
        foreach (string line in lines )
        {
            string[] col = line.Split(',');
            Console.WriteLine(col[0]);
            Console.WriteLine(col[1]);
            Console.WriteLine(col[2]);
            Console.WriteLine(col[3]);
        }
```

But that only gives me values for one line. 
This is the VB.Net code that i am trying to duplicate:

```
        FileOpen(1, "stockfile.txt", OpenMode.Input)

    Do While Not EOF(1)

        Input(1, GTIN)
        Input(1, GTIN_INFO)
        Input(1, PRICE)

        stock(No).GTIN = GTIN
        stock(No).GTIN_INFO = GTIN_INFO
        stock(No).PRICE = PRICE

        No = No + 1

    Loop

    FileClose(1)
```

In the above example, the Input imports per comma, then i set each value to a value inside an array. How could i do this in C#?
Thanks for any help

Comment: the first thing to check would be why the C# program returns only data from the first line. Is there a newline between "records"? because the code you have, with `ReadAllLines` should do this properly.

Comment: You could use File.ReadAllLines method.

Comment: but they do, don't they? first line of first code section. @james, the file name is different - sure that the contents are the same?

Comment: @dlatikay What do you mean by "records", are you referring to my stock file? if so, there is no line that's just the formatting of the question. I can see the file name is different, that code was pulled from a previous program. The C# has the correct file :), and yes the contents are the same

Comment: ok then I see what's happening. The `ReadAllLines` call would only return more than one item for the `lines` array when there was actually a newline separation. In your case, you would have to continue looping over `col` and just define that at every fourth index, a new item starts. one more thing: why do you read four items in the C# version, when VB seems to read only three tokens per item?

Comment: I agree, the code is fine - I just tested it -  the issue should be with the text file.

Comment: consider using a csv parser.

Comment: @TamásSzabó yes it seems the text file was the issue with the problem of it printing only one line. thanks

Comment: @dlatikay it's solved now but apologies for the formatting of the question and details, since what you pointed out is correct. it is because in vb.net i only wanted 3 values, and in c# i wanted 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how I would replicate what your VB code does:

```
namespace so43807152
{
    struct Record
    {
        public string GTIN;
        public string GTIN_INFO;
        public string WHATEVER;
        public decimal PRICE;
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var stock = new List<Record>();

            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("stock.txt");
            foreach (var line in lines)
            {
                var col = line.Split(',');
                for (int i = 0; i < col.Length; i += 4)
                {
                    var record = new Record
                    {
                        GTIN = col[i],
                        GTIN_INFO = col[i + 1],
                        WHATEVER = col[i + 2],
                        PRICE = decimal.Parse(col[i + 3])
                    };
                    stock.Add(record);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this way it does not matter if commas and newlines are used for record separation. It would not work when GTIN_INFO could contain commas (true also for the VB version).

(I took your apparent change from three-field items to four-field items into account, now knowing what the third column actually is.)

LINQ enthusiasts would pack most of that into one line.

Comment: His code was fine, the issue was with the text file.

Comment: d'oh. then he can still vfc as "a problem that can no longer be reproduced"

Comment: @TamásSzabó The issue wasn't only the text file, i wanted to know how i could do the same code in C# and dlatikay answered that

Answer (score 0):

I did this as a little LINQPad Query using your sample file so you can see another option.

```cs
void Main()
{
    var filename = @"C:\Documents\SampleText.txt";

    var stocks = new List<Record>();    
    using (TextReader reader = File.OpenText(filename))
    {
        while (reader.Peek() > -1)
        {           
            var values = reader.ReadLine().Split(',');
            stocks.Add(new Record
            {
                GTIN = values[0],
                GTIN_INFO = values[1],
                WHATEVER = values[2],
                PRICE = values[3]
            });
        }
    }
    stocks.Dump();
}

// Define other methods and classes here
class Record
{
    public string GTIN { get; set; }
    public string GTIN_INFO { get; set; }
    public string WHATEVER { get; set; }
    public string PRICE { get; set; }
}
```

Here are the results that I get.

[image]

Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: yes it helps, but there are a lot of things used which i have yet to learn, apologies for that i am new to c#

Comment: No apologies required @james.  We all have to start somewhere and I'm just happy to help out a future developer.

Comment: @james Can you mark my answer if it helped you?  Thanks.

Comment: i upvoted it as useful but it doesnt display as i'm a new user, and the answer before helped the most